# How to make a function that adds a number to a file and loads itself number+1 again?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make make a simple inventory manager and for that I want to save the newest line in a file, such that previous +1 for 3 tabs?

```py
def read():
    file_location = os.path.abspath('.')
    txt_location = os.path.join(file_location, 'data', 'resume data.txt')
    with open(txt_location, 'r') as file:
        sorok = file.read().splitlines()
    lista = sorok
    return lista

def save(data):
    file_location = os.path.abspath('.')
    txt_location = os.path.join(file_location, 'data', 'resume data.txt')
    with open(txt_location, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines("%s\n" % dat for dat in data)

data = read()

extra_row_raktar = 0
extra_row_bolt = 0
extra_row_webshop = 0

row_raktar = int(read()[0]) + int(extra_row_raktar)
row_bolt = int(read()[1]) + int(extra_row_bolt)
row_webshop = int(read()[2]) + int(extra_row_webshop)

save([row_raktar, row_bolt, row_webshop])

def raktar():
    global extra_row_raktar
    extra_row_raktar = extra_row_raktar + 1
    print(extra_row_raktar)

raktar()
save([row_raktar, row_bolt, row_webshop])
```

So `row_raktar` should be incremented by 1 using `extra_row_raktar`, but it doesn't. The code executes without error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your code, you have this:

```py
raktar()  
save([row_raktar, row_bolt, row_webshop])
```

Calling `raktar()` increments `extra_row_raktar` by 1. But then, `row_raktar` is still set to the previous value (current value in file + `extra_row_raktar=0`). So, the value saved in the file would still be the original `row_raktar` value. Nothing was changed.

You need to update `row_raktar` before the next call to `save`.

```
raktar()
row_raktar += int(extra_row_raktar)
row_bolt += int(extra_row_bolt)
row_webshop += int(extra_row_webshop)
save([row_raktar, row_bolt, row_webshop])
```

---

There's some parts of your code that can be improved.

You are calling `read()` multiple times here:

```
row_raktar = int(read()[0]) + int(extra_row_raktar)
row_bolt = int(read()[1]) + int(extra_row_bolt)
row_webshop = int(read()[2]) + int(extra_row_webshop)
```

You can just call `read()` once:

```
data = read()
row_raktar = int(data[0]) + int(extra_row_raktar)
row_bolt = int(data[1]) + int(extra_row_bolt)
row_webshop = int(data[2]) + int(extra_row_webshop)
save([row_raktar, row_bolt, row_webshop])
```